# What repo provides package 'cd-boot-images-amd64'?

Tags: apt, pxe

According to https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-server-installer-on-amd64/16620 there is a package or meta-package named 'cd-boot-images-amd64' but apt on focal fossa (with no "extra" sources) cannot find it. Perhaps it's quicker to manually download the images but I would need a list of filenames and checksums at the very least.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cd-boot-images-amd64 says it's a package in hirsuite, impish and jammy. Not existing in focal ... you'll get everything you need from the official download. for example: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ in the file SHA256SUMS

Comment: Thanks. Somehow the search engines I used didn't find this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cd-boot-images-amd64), this package is only available on Ubuntu 21.04 and above.

You can still try using the package from 21.04 in 20.04.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cd-boot-images-amd64/cd-boot-images-amd64_14_all.deb
sudo apt install ./cd-boot-images-amd64_14_all.deb
```

Comment: Current path is http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cd-boot-images-amd64/cd-boot-images-amd64_20_all.deb